# get indexOf element which type is array

Tags: arrays, swift, indexof

How I can figure out to get index of element which type is array?

For instance, I have property
 `let videosArrays = [[Video]]()`
and some element of this array `let videos = [Video]()`

The video has some properties:

```
var thumbnailImageURL: String?
var title: String?
var numberOfViews: NSNumber?
var uploadDate: NSData?
```

I need to get index of `videos` in `videosArrays`
Xcode gives this syntax:

```
<predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool(Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool>
```

How I can implement this?

```
let index = videosArrays.indexOf({ (<#Self.Generator.Element#>) -> Bool in
            <#code#>
        })
```

I can't figure out how to use this to find index.

Comment: can you specify which object index you want?

Comment: index of what video?

Comment: I need indexOf `videos` which are element of `videosArrays`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `indexOf`, `contains` and some other array methods easily, the objects have to conform to `Equatable` protocol.

Thus, you should probably do the following:

```
extension Video: Equatable { }
func ==(lhs: Video, rhs: Video) -> Bool {
    return lhs.thumbnailImageURL == rhs.thumbnailImageURL &&
        lhs.title == rhs.title &&
        lhs.numberOfViews == rhs.numberOfViews &&
        lhs.uploadDate == rhs.uploadDate
}
```

Comment: thanx! But What about arrays? I have array which consists of elements which also arrays? and I need to find index of array element in array

Comment: Then you should use the closure `indexOf` takes as argument:   

`videosArray.indexOf { $0 == [Video(...)] }`, thus comparing each element of array to the array you want.

Comment: I can't figure out how to implement this closure (